# How to publish asp boilerplate project on Ubuntu 16.04 using Docker?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to publish my project using ABP to Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker, I'm still confused, where I put the dockerfile in abp project? maybe my dockerfile it's wrong,

**Here my dockerfile:**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT docker

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I found that's code from the internet , Anyone can help me? I need an explanation so I can learn.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is probably to use the built-in support in Visual Studio:

1. Right-click your project
2. Select Add | Docker Support
3. Select "Linux"
4. Click OK

This will add a project named "docker-compose" to your solution. You can either right-click this and select "build" to build a docker image of your project, or you can open a command prompt in your solution folder and run `docker-compose build`.

It will also generate a `dockerfile` in your project folder, which you can add any required environment variables, etc. to.

Comment: can't add sir :(

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Srudio 2017 sir

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110407/add-docker-support-missing.html) - it seems you to enable it during the setup.

Comment: Docker support menu it's not missing sir but disabled. Im using https://aspnetboilerplate.com/

Comment: Since ABP is just an ASP.Net core project, it doesn't make a difference. I downloaded an ABP project and sure enough the option is [there](https://i.imgur.com/YdaHVUt.jpg). Please ensure you have enabled the feature in Visual Studio 2017 and have Docker installed and running on your machine.